# Represent $f(x)$ with $g(x)$ when the taylor expension has specific dependency

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series, taylor-expansion, formal-power-series

If I have $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ like that:$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {a_nx^n} {n}$$
How can I find u(x) such: $f(u(x))=g(x)$?
I also know that the series $(a_n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\,a_1\ne 0\,$ then we can find the [series reversion](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/s/s214.htm) $\, h(x) := f^{-1}(x)\,$ which satisfies
$$ x = h(f(x)) = f(h(x)). \tag{1}$$ Then,
defining $$u(x) := h(g(x)) \tag{2}$$ we find the expected
$$ f(u(x)) = f(h(g(x)) = g(x). \tag{3}$$
The first 3 terms of the expansion of the power series are:
$$ h(x) = \frac1{a_1}x - \frac{a_2}{a_1^3}x^2 
+\frac{2a_2^2-a_1a_3}{a_1^5}x^3 + \dots \tag{4} $$
and
$$ u(x) = x - \frac{a_2}{2a_1}x^2
+\frac{3a_2^2-2a_1a_3}{3a_1^2}x^3 + \dots \tag{5} $$
where I used a [computer algebra system PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) to find the power series
with code similar to the following:

```
fx = a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + O(x^4);
gx = intformal(fx/x);
hx = serreverse(fx)
ux = subst(hx, x, gx)
```

Comment: Can you please write $u(x)$ with a sum? I can't understand the pattern. thank you a lot.

Comment: @pgp1 Sorry, but it is not a simple thing. I don't see a pattern either, but that is not a requirement. The series exists and can be computed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $f(x),g(x),u(x)$ to be [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series).

Let $^{-1}$ denote the compositional inverse.

$$f(u(x))=g(x)$$

$$u(x)=f^{-1}(g(x))$$

$f^{-1}$ is the compositional inverse of $f$. $f^{-1}$ is a formal power series iff $a_1\neq 0$. You can find $f^{-1}$ then e.g. by [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

You can find the composition of $f^{-1}$ and $g$ e.g. by [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).